# Sites for licensing of Meditation sounds and music

Tags: instrumental

I am planning to create a meditation app which will have meditation music.

There are many nice youtube channels which don't provide licensing options for any of their music. Is there any well-known place/channel/studio which offers licensing option for commercial use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get royalty-free music (even for commercial use) under a creative commons license from [Incompetech](https://incompetech.filmmusic.io/search/). Note: if you want to use the music for free they do require attribution.
Or go [here](https://www.annafrolik.com/blog/2019/2/10/royalty-free-guided-meditation-music) for a list of sites providing meditation music you can license.